# Yeoman generator composeWith

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am building a generator which uses another sub-generator, using composeWith.

I installed my generator using `npm install -g generator-my-generator`. When running the generator complains that I do not have my sub-generator installed.

My problem is that I don't want to install the sub-generator globally. I tried using it as a dependency / peerDependency (as suggested [here](https://tlvince.com/composable-yeoman-generators)), but it did not help.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the path in `composeWith` third argument:

```
this.composeWith('generator:name', {}, {
    local: require.resolve('generator-foo/generators/name')
});
```

`require.resolve` is usually your best bet, but some generators (like [generator-node](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node/blob/master/index.js)) provide all the paths inside the main module so you don't have to know the package structure.